# How run logic when reactive repository return empty Mono?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive

I have interface like below to find Entity by phoneNumber in MongoDB:

```
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<User, String> {
    
    Mono<User> findByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
}
```

This code is working and throw exception when Mono is empty, but I don't like it.

```
userRepository.findByPhoneNumber(PHONE_NUMBER)

    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("user phone number not exist: " + PHONE_NUMBER)))
    .subscribe(result -> {

        // DO LOGIC HERE

    });
```

I would like to do something like this. I don't want to throwing exception, because it is normal that User Entity could be not found in MongoDB. I would like to to different logic when Mono is empty.

```
userRepository.findByPhoneNumber(PHONE_NUMBER)

    .switchIfEmpty(() -> {

        // DO OTHER LOGIC HERE when Mono is empty

    })
    .subscribe(result -> {

        // DO LOGIC HERE

    });
```

Comment: What is your switchOnEmpty logic? Subscribe logic will run on whatever's returned from switchOnEmpty

Comment: You are throwing the exception yourself, don't throw an exception (in this case don't use `Mono.error` but execute your logic.

Comment: How can I execute my logic? I would like just execute log.info for example, but .switchIfEmpty need Mono instance :/

Answer (score 3):

I think you could get a better code by using the Spring WebFlux Documentation [Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html)

So instead of:

```
userRepository.findByPhoneNumber(PHONE_NUMBER)

    .switchIfEmpty(() -> {

        // DO OTHER LOGIC HERE when Mono is empty

    })
    .subscribe(result -> {

        // DO LOGIC HERE

    });
```

You would have something like

```
 public Mono<User> findByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) { 
        return repository.findByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .switchIfEmpty(Throw YOUR_EX());
    }
```

If you don't want to throw an Exception inside your `switchIfEmpty`, you could try returnin a `Mono.Empty`:

```
 public Mono<User> findByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) { 
        return repository.findByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
               log.error("No Users found with phoneNumber [{}]", phoneNumber);
               return Mono.empty();
    }));
 }
```

Also you can get some detailed info [here](https://medium.com/@nikeshshetty/5-common-mistakes-of-webflux-novices-f8eda0cd6291).

Comment: I don't want to throw exception I would like to just log this problem, but in .switchIfEmpty creating Mono is needed.
Istead of "// DO LOGIC HERE" I would like to "log.info("blablabla")

Comment: Not sure why you don't want to throw an exception but you could try using `Mono.defer` to get an empty response. I've updated the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: I agree, should throw and exception. Bad code smell to use an empty Mono as a conditional.

Comment: I mean, having an exception thrown is basicaly getting to know that your application has made some nasty things, and furthermore you can use some tools (like Kibana) to provide an Error statics, so you can evaluate what Exceptions are being thrown and analyse why they are being throw. Having to search a `loged` information on a production environment is really time consuming and very stressfull.